# Automatically classifying user activity/sessions on a website?

Tags: sql, r, classification

I have a large body of records pertaining to user activity on a website. What I want to do is some sort of classification on each user as they navigate my website. Every algorithm I found so far uses one row at a time, but I want to take into account the sequence in which rows appear, as well. That is, there is a time component to the data and dependencies between rows. I want to be able to tell the algorithm/software that it should take each set of rows with the same SessionIdentifier to be the same "record"

Example of training data:

```
Bob   | Page1  | SessionIdentifier1 | timestamp
Bob   | Page2  | SessionIdentifier1 | timestamp
Bob   | Page3  | SessionIdentifier1 | timestamp
Alice | Page1  | SessionIdentifier2 | timestamp
Alice | Page4  | SessionIdentifier2 | timestamp
Alice | Page1  | SessionIdentifier2 | timestamp
Alice | Page3  | SessionIdentifier2 | timestamp
Alice | Page2  | SessionIdentifier3 | timestamp
Alice | Page24 | SessionIdentifier3 | timestamp
Alice | Page34 | SessionIdentifier3 | timestamp
etc...
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of a place to get started on this project?

Comment: This is not a specific programming question. If you need help choosing statistical methods or machine learning techniques to analyze data, try posting to [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead. Otherwise, make your question much more specific about the programming challenge you are struggling with.

Comment: This is a well known problem in web analytics where you want to classify a sequence of requests by a given user over a given timespan as a single "visit". It's easy to do in R but your question is too vague. Post some real data - enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a good start for ya, but you need work on your understanding of the statistical modeling and pre-processing of data.

FYI: This will error out at the end because I did not handle the index so you can go ahead and correct that.

Also,  SequenceVar this will become your factor that is inputted into the model, also I do not know what your data looks like but if it has too many levels then it will not be able to be handled by most models.

```
library(sqldf)
library(reshape)
Test = structure(list(UserName = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alice", "Bob", 
"Chris"), class = "factor"), Page = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("Page1", 
"Page2", "Page24", "Page3", "Page34", "Page35", "Page4", "Page5", 
"Page6"), class = "factor"), SessionID = c(1965520.44, 1965520.44, 
1965520.44, 2995108.043, 2995108.043, 2995108.043, 2995108.043, 
2995108.043, 2995108.043, 2995108.043, 1842002.603, 1842002.603, 
1842002.603, 1842002.603, 1842002.603), CT = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("UserName", "Page", 
"SessionID", "CT"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

Test$RowID = 1:nrow(Test)
Test$Page = as.character(Test$Page )

# First I would switch it to binary variables for classification
Pivot = cast(Test, UserName +  SessionID  ~ Page )
Pivot[is.na(Pivot)] <- 0
Pivot

# Second I would create the sequence and compare the results to the previous model
Test$SequenceVar = ''

for(i in 1:nrow(Test)){

Sequence = Test[2][i,]

for(Seek in 1:999){

if(Test[1][i,] == Test[1][i+Seek,])
    {

    Sequence = paste(Sequence,"-",Test[2][i+Seek,],sep="")
    Test$SequenceVar[i] = Sequence

        }
        else if(Test[1][i,] != Test[1][i+Seek,]){break}
    }
}

library(sqldf)

sqldf("Select UserName,Page,SessionID,CT,RowID,SequenceVar
        from Test b
        where RowID  in (select min(RowID )
                  from Test b1
                  where b.UserName = b1.UserName
                  group by UserName)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point! Is there a resource in particular you would recommend for me to learn more?

Comment: @towelyey I would start out with a strong understanding of SQL, then move on to R & Python. Some of the best resources are free. Check out udemy, coursera, edx, and YouTube. Once you have a stable coding background look into data mining which focuses on the following: identifying sources, cleaning, variable selection, variable transformation, and variable creation. Best of luck cheers!